# Null lines and degenerate plane

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, definition, geometry

Can anyone explain me what null lines are and degenerate plane? I  don't know  anything about it, I don't have physics background and I am a mathematics student and please tell me if there is any good reference for it so that a beginner can understand it.

Comment: I am assuming you are asking about the notion of nullness in relativity.  In that case a null line (more generally, curve) is a line (curve) whose proper length is zero.  This is possible in relativity because the metric (pseudometric) is not positive-definite, and so there are non-zero tangent vectors with zero length.  I am no sure what a null plane is but presumably a surface all of whose tangent vectors are null.

Answer (score 2):

A null line is a line in the complex projective plane with slope $i$ or $-i$. An condition in the definition of a projective plane is

iii) There are four points such that no line is incident with more than two of them.

Degenerate planes do not satisfy this condition. There are seven degenerate planes. See Albert, A. Adrian; Sandler, Reuben (1968), An Introduction to Finite Projective Planes, New York: Holt, Rinehart and Winston.